# Trap adapter on wall drain rough in - what is this?

Tags: plumbing

I'm installing a new p-trap for a vanity that is roughed in. I'm trying to get the trap adapter as close to the wall as possible, so the escutcheon will cover the adapter (it will be exposed), but there is some sort of collar around the pipe where it comes out the wall: [image: wall drain rough in]

Is there some way  I can remove this collar so I can get my adapter up next to the wall?

Comment: Disclaimer: that's one of the weirdest things I've ever seen.  OK, have you tried to use a pair of channel lock pliers to turn that collar?  It looks like a compression-style nut, just as you'd expect on a sewer line... but that also looks like PVC, which isn't what you'd expect.  If you haven't, please try it.  These nuts aren't meant to be super tight, so you shouldn't need to apply more than moderate force.  Let us know if you have tried this.

Comment: If it doesn't move, it could be a 2" to 1 ¼" reducing bushing. In that case it will be glued in. 

Comment: @ArchonOSX indeed - I scrapped off some of the paint on it and it says 2" x 1 1/2", so it does indeed seem to be a reducing bushing of some kind. So, I think I'm just going to leave it and glue my adapter as close to the reducing bushing as I can.

Answer (score 3):

That is a 2" tee with a reducing bushing glued into it. You will want a "deep box type escutcheon" which will bell over the fitting and hide it. They look like this:

[image]